# Refactoring/Restructuring tool for Java

Tags: java, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have a large monolithic webapplication that I whish to break apart into smaller modules. As a first step I'd like to change the package hierarchy which currently looks like:

```
 - com.companyname.project
  - dao
     - bean
         - booking // possibly containing more sub packages
         - core   
         ... etc etc (there are a bunch of others as well)
     - service
         - booking // possibly containing more sub packages
         - core   
         ... etc etc  
  - logic
     - bean
         - booking // possibly containing more sub packages
         - core   
         ... etc etc
     - service
         - booking
         - core   
         ... etc etc
  - web
     - bean  // same substructure as above...
     - service  // same substructure as above...
     - taglib  // same substructure as above...
     - util
```

I would like it if the package structure used for instance `booking` as the package name below `com.companyname.project`

Now I am wondering if there is a tool that could for instance use a simple regex to do the restructuring for me.

E.g.
`com.companyname.project.dao.bean.booking`
would become:
`com.companyname.project.booking.dao.bean`

and

`com.companyname.project.dao.service.booking`
would become:
`com.companyname.project.booking.dao.service`

I could use Eclipse and drag and drop the packages, but I am looking for something that could do this with a minimal of my involvment, since it will be very repetetive.

Comment: If you had started working on it in Eclipse instead of writing this question, you'd be half done by now.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Trust me... I wouldn't ;)

Comment: @Emil h Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @user1283633 Nope. We ended up refactoring using Eclipse, carefully moving each class/package and ensuring references to class names in a bunch of different xml files got updated. One thing to watch out for is if you have serialized a class you need to handle that those classes no longer exist (since it's package will have changed). It took us roughly two man weeks to refactor the entire project. But, it is a badly structured project so YMMV :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the Java IDE with refactoring compatibilities:

- IntelliJ IDEA (The best refactoring support). It has open source community edition and closed source ultimate edition.
- Eclipse (open source)
- NetBeans (open source)

I don't recommend you using regexp search/replace since it is error prone.

Comment: I wouldn't use a regexp for this. However I would like it if for instance the rename refactoring in eclipse could take a regexp and use that for the name change.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Java itself?  I believe in your current scenario, you could easily write a small Java program to do the exact refactorings you're talking about and ensure that nothing is missed along the way.

You could write a method that takes "pre" (i.e. "com.companyname.project.dao.bean.booking") and "post" (i.e. "com.companyname.project.booking.dao.bean") params and copies the "pre" structure appropriately into the "post" structure.

In this program, I envision a main method and a "convertPackage(pre,post)" method.  You could then have an array of your "pre" and "post" structures and loop through converting them over to the new.  It would be best to do this copying into some sort of temp directory and not muck with the original as an added safety measure.

Maybe my thinking is too simple on this, but I could see a program built to do this refactoring in 1/2 a day or less.

You'll get the added benefit of knowing **exactly** what is changing rather than the insecurity that comes with these automated tools that *may* do it right for you or may not...